# In JavaScript, how does an object "obj" that doesn't have the property named "foo" be able to give a value using obj["foo"]?

Tags: javascript

I read in the book Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja, that we can use `document.all["id"]` to get **all** elements in the document that has such ID, if the browser supports it.  (although supposedly we should only have one element with a particular ID).

But `document.all` returns an `HTMLAllCollection` object, and I see in Chrome that it has 9 elements, like an array (9 elements, as set up in jsfiddle).  So I can understand why `document.all[9]` can return the element, but why can `document.all["foo"]` return it too?  If we define `var obj = { foo : 123 }`, then we can say `obj["foo"]`, but `document.all` is not an object with a key `foo`.  So supposedly, `document.all["foo"]` shouldn't be able to return an element like that.

**Note: this question is not to ask about the use of `document.all`, and it is not about asking to have two elements with the same ID on the page.  It is asking why an object `obj` that does not seem to have the key `foo` is able to give a value using `obj["foo"]`  I do not know why this is not a valid programming question.**

sample code:

1 element with such ID:
http://jsfiddle.net/ArR5x/5/

2 elements with such ID:
http://jsfiddle.net/ArR5x/10/

**Update: Dan Tao is correct.  It is due to some properties being enumerable and some are not, and we can easily produce the same situation if ECMAScript 5 is supported: http://jsfiddle.net/Akdp9/12/ The is a valid question about JavaScript, and the real answer is that it is due to the enumerable attribute of a property.**

Comment: IDs are unique. Moreover, `document.all` is nonstandard

Comment: I am not saying we should all rush in and write code like this.  I am merely asking by what mechanism can it work

Comment: Who downvoted this? Bad code is not a reason to downvote a question.

Comment: I think the purist who will crucify anybody who dared to type `document.all` on the keyboard downvoted it

Comment: You're asking about a deprecated non-standard feature and using it to do something that one is not supposed to do. IDs are unique by the DOM specification which document.all is not even a part of. Any answer would be based on implementation detail and would be nonstandard.

Comment: @JosephSilber Votes indicate usefulness, not good/bad code. I guess someone thought it was not useful.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum but it is still a standard JavaScript behavior.  Or say, if somebody writes a library that has `$.myAll` and it behaves like this, then you can still wonder by what mechanism does it work, can't you?

Comment: @動靜能量 Are you asking _how it's implemented internally_ ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum NO, I am saying you can say `obj["foo"]` if you define `var obj = { foo : 123 }`, but how can `document.all["foo"]` behave the same?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32853/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum so you think you can downvote any question because you think it is not useful?  So if you don't use prototypal inheritance and don't think it is useful for you, you would downvote every question on StackOverflow about prototypal inheritance?

Comment: @動靜能量 I have reversed my downvote since you have _completely_ revised your question since you originally posted it. (no reference to `document.all` in title for example, asking about something that makes more sense. I'm satisfied that my initial down-vote drove you to improve your question! The correct answer imho is @Esailija 's

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it is actually the same question.  The difference is that it won't drive any people who would do no thinking and just think "document.all? No! Downvote.  Close it!"

Comment: @動靜能量 That was _not_ the point of downvoting and close voting it. _Read_ your original question - see for yourself. It wasn't clear at all that you meant you were asking why DOM objects behave differently. It sounded like you were trying to do voodoo with document.all and multiple identical IDs. A good way to ask it would have been something like "Why do some DOM objects behave differently from JavaScript objects".

Comment: an object you get back from document.all is voodoo?  Good for you, Benjamin

Comment: @動靜能量 yes it is voodoo, the reasoning in the "correct" answer is easily invalidated and your conclusions are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand why you're confused. Let me explain a couple of things to clear up any confusion. Some of this you may already know, but I'm going to cover all of it just to be safe.

First, an array-like object can still have properties just like any other object. Even a vanilla `Array` is like this.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.foo = "bar";
arr["foo"]; // => "bar"
```

So it seems perfectly reasonable that after parsing the DOM, the browser populates `document.all` with properties corresponding to every ID on the page, even though `HTMLAllCollection` is rather array-like.

Second, an object's properties are not necessarily all created equal. You may have tried this and noticed a lack of any "foo" property:

```
Object.keys(document.all)
// => ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "length"]
```

However, "foo" really **is** a property of `document.all`. You can verify that pretty easily:

```
document.all.foo;
// => [<div id=​"foo">​hello​</div>​, <div id=​"foo">​world​</div>​]

document.all.hasOwnProperty("foo") // => true
```

The issue here is that it is not an **enumerable** property. This means it won't show up in a `for`/`in` loop, and it also explains why you don't see it when you all `Object.keys`.

You can confirm this with [the `propertyIsEnumerable` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable):

```
document.all.propertyIsEnumerable("foo"); // => false
```

So in the end it's not so much of a mystery. Arbitrary properties can be assigned to the `document.all` object, just as they can with arrays. And that is the case here; the properties just aren't enumerable.

Comment: So why doesn't `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` work on it? Consider `Object.keys(Math)` vs `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)`, the latter would plow through enumerable false if that was the case.

Comment: @Esailija: Ha, you've stumped me there. Clearly your answer is more accurate than mine. I felt compelled to write this much because I actually sensed from the OP's question that he was confused by more fundamental JS things here. But of course you're right that when we're dealing with host objects, the rules become more malleable at the whim of the browser developers.

Comment: but why is this more advanced topic closed as "off topic"?

Answer (score 2):

DOM is not implemented in Javascript and most rules of Javascript don't apply to it.

For example, in Chrome `!!document.all` evaluates to `false` even though in Javascript rules, all objects are truthy.

Comment: interesting... you are saying, what DOM or DOM method returns, is a JavaScript object or value, but doesn't have to follow JavaScript rules?

Comment: Those are host objects so they don't have to follow the ES spec. And in this specific case, Chrome and IE11 do that basically because `if (document.all) { console.log("this ain't IE4 so I refuse to enter this block"); }`

Answer (score 0):

Just because you aren't supposed to have multiple elements with the same ID does not mean that you can't query them. A CSS selector will apply to multiple elements with the same ID, as will `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#foo');
```

can also return multiple elements.

Here's the fiddle to prove it: http://jsfiddle.net/EgBbN/

Comment: Just because it 'happens to work' doesn't mean that it should. This behavior could be changed tomorrow - relying on it is extremely risky and irresponsible. Moreover, this behavior is not specified anywhere, the whole concept of 'selecting elements from an invalid DOM' is not specified anywhere, nor should it be.

Comment: You can always use `[id=foo]` selector

Comment: @Esailija - You're still selecting by ID, which should be unique. I don't think that an implementation that only returns the first element for `[id=foo]` would not be a correct implementation.

Comment: @JosephSilber Right, but selecting `#foo` and getting two elements back is [not specified like you imply in your answer](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#id-selectors). What Esailija suggested on the other hand might work.

Comment: @JosephSilber I am not asking to prove or disprove it.  I am asking if an object doesn't have such a key, how can `obj["foo"]` return a value

Comment: @動靜能量 What makes you think document.all doesn't have a `foo` key?  `document.all["foo"]===document.all.foo` and `document.all["gooblediegoog"]===undefined` both return true in your jsfiddle.

Comment: It is because when I examine it in Chrome's console, only the property names that are numbers and `length` are shown